# Web3 Python Gas Gwei not working: intrinsic gas too low

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

Why is the gas fee not working? If I remove the gas fee, the transaction works. But if I add a gas fee, the transaction fails and returns error:

{'code': -32000, 'message': 'intrinsic gas too low'}

```
web3matic = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(matic))

                    nonce = web3matic.eth.get_transaction_count(walletAddress)
                    result = contract.functions.buy(item, int(price)).buildTransaction({
                        'from': walletAddress,
                        'nonce': nonce,
                        'gas': 21000,
                        'gasPrice': web3matic.toWei(700, 'gwei'),
                    })
                    print(result)
```

Comment: Can it be that you set the gas fee too low? Maybe you need to increase the value of `gasPrice`?

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you are setting the gas field to 21000, which is the correct amount of gas for a simple value/coin transfer transaction.

Since you are calling a function in a smart contract, you have to provide more gas: 21000 + a fee for every byte you are sending (4 gas for a zero byte, 68 gas for non-zeros)).

You should have a [data field](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/v5/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.send_transaction) where you can check how many bytes you are sending :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting gas to 3000000 and using `w3.eth.gasPrice` for gasPrice

Context: Polygon increased the min gas price for 1 Gwei to 30 in Oct 2021
https://forum.matic.network/t/recommended-min-gas-price-setting/2531

```
web3matic = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(matic))

                    nonce = web3matic.eth.get_transaction_count(walletAddress)
                    result = contract.functions.buy(item, int(price)).buildTransaction({
                        'from': walletAddress,
                        'nonce': nonce,
                        'gas': 3000000,
                        'gasPrice': web3matic.eth.gasPrice,
                    })
                    print(result)
```